# UICollectionView getting Images from UiImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a collection view. I want to upload five images for each cell and also Fetch images into that cell if already present from `JSON`, if not using `UIImagePicker` on `UIButton` action have to upload five images one by one, it can be four, three or single one.

The images if already present replace the previous. Something like this

[image: this is how i get]

Now I want to replace and change these `JSONImages`.
i have done Something like this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 MG_PhotoCollectionViewCell *cell = (MG_PhotoCollectionViewCell *) . [self.collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kProductCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



NSString *myPatternString = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
NSLog(@"myPatternString %@",myPatternString);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myPatternString]];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

cell.overlayButton.layer.cornerRadius = cell.overlayButton.frame.size.height/2;
cell.overlayButton.clipsToBounds = YES;

[cell.overlayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(getImages:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

cell.overlayButton.tag = indexPath.item;
```

and it picker controller as

```
 -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info{


// UIImage *imagepick = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

UIImage *image= info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
if (!image) image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

[self.dataArray addObject:image];

[self.collectionView reloadData];



[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    NSLog(@"Finished image picking");
}];
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you have to set bool value for check that new image select or existing image change

Comment: how can i change image with the button that attach to the cell..?

Comment: Just wait for couple of min.s I'll give you full code for this.

Comment: thanku buddy ...waiting

Comment: https://gist.github.com/himanshu-benzatine/e4d8346dd220e2075858d516c273213e @Dheeraj refer this file

Comment: data array is my JSON array,what do i do with that here u have used NsmutableDictionary @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: ya i use Nsmutabledictionary for convert image into data to transfer or send image to server .

Comment: what do i do with my JSON array then ,can you tell me buddy stuck in this also what is  'kAddNewImage' u have used do i have to enum these things ..?

Comment: I have posted my answer below, just check it. Happy coding......

Comment: @Dheeraj ya i use enum for check new image or update image

Comment: the code you have given does i have to make some changes or use  as it is .....?bcoz i dont have much time to go through it ....please help ...?@HimanshuMoradiya

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following the steps:

**1)** When you get the web service response, make an array of images you have in it. Here, for your demo, I have taken two image arrays: `jsonImgArray` and `currentImgArray`.

When you get the response, take your images in `jsonImgArray` array as well as `currentImgArray`.

**2)** You can assign images from currentImgArray to your `collectionViewCell`'s ImageView as you have done above. By this, you will get the images already uploaded.

**3)** If you want to change the image, you can write your `collectionView`'s `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method as below:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [currentImgArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@""];
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;    
//    Code to manage change image as you have coded above
}
```

Here, selectedIndexPath is of `NSIndexPath` data type.

**OR**

**3)** Your can code your button action method same as `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` you just need to maintain your `indexPath`. For that, you can assign `collectionView` item index value to respective button's tag so that you can get your `indexPath` value as

```
-(void)btnAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSInteger item = sender.tag;
    selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:0];
}
```

Now
**4)** You can change your code of image `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method as

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{

    UICollectionView *collectionView;
    UIImage *img = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [currentImgArray replaceObjectAtIndex:selectedIndexPath.row withObject:img];

    [collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[selectedIndexPath]];
//  You above code other that this functionality.
}
```

Now, if you want to check if there are any changes in your images, you can write some code to compare array images of jsonImgArray and currentImgArray.

Comment: what is selectedIndexPath ..?@Er.Vihar

Comment: @Dheeraj SelectedIndexPath is an NSIndexPath type object to manage selected index from collectionView DidSelect method to image view's didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo Method.

Comment: why do you have use JsonImgArray ,...?you re not using it..?

Comment: I have not mentioned it in my code but I have detailed in my concluding statement that if you want to track that You have any images changed or not than you required that array as that array contains the initial data, i.e. before any changes and currentImgArray contains modified image list

Comment: cell.overlayButton.tag = indexPath.item; do i have to something with this in my cellForrowa index...?

Comment: @Dheeraj Yes. By this you can manage indexpath at button action method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131594/discussion-between-er-vihar-and-dheeraj).